# Android touch input delay problems for a timing critical game. Is there a delay before onTouchEvent is called?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

So we're working on the android version of the iPhone game Snake Race (it's a cool game). However, we seem to be getting a delay on the touch inputs just big enough to make a difference. (The snake might turn a step later than you intended) After getting almost used to the android version, the iPhone version feels like a blessing.

The question is whether there is a delay from androids side in calling the onTouchEvent() method? (I'm using Samsung Galaxy S2) If so, is there any neat tricks to circumvent the issue?(Even if it means using the NDK)

This is the current implementation touch handling:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {      
    int action = event.getAction();
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || 
            (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){     
        Run run = GameVars.run;

        if(run != null){
            if(run.paused){
                run.paused = false;
            }else{
                if(event.getX(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT) < GameVars.width/2){
                    run.addTap(-1);

                }else{
                    run.addTap(1);

                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the addTap method:

```
public void addTap(int newDir) {
    if(newDir == -tapDir){
        taps++;
        tapDir *= -1;
    }
}
```

And then every frame, taps is checked, and if it's greater than zero (and we're allowed to turn atm) we turn.

It all works fine and is reliable, but there is a consistent delay (maybe 2-3 frames, which is enough to make the iPhone snake seriously more maneuverable).

Any feedback is apprieciated!

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe, it waits a few milliseconds to see if it was a  drag event or just a click event. Not sure how android system works though. You could try looking into that

Comment: Anecdotally, the Galaxy Note seems to have terrible input lag on its home screen. I'm not sure whether the problem is Android or the device. I'm curious as to whether Project Butter made any difference to input lag for apps.

Comment: I'm also looking forward to testing Jelly Bean, and see whether they managed to improve it, and by how much. I'll see if I can do a methodical test once I get a jelly bean rom for my S2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come to realize that it is indeed a delay from the side of the device. It is not big but it is there, and it varies quite a lot between different android phones. My Galaxy S2 has a bigger delay than most of the newer HTC models I've tested. I've also made new project where a touch switch background / play a sound (I know that has an additional delay) etc. And I can't seem to find anything that circumvents the problem.

Comment: If you enable "Show touches" in the developer options you can easily see the lag from real input to your app, and from your app handling the event to your drawing (draw a debug sprite that updates to the touch x,y).

Comment: The first post, and my encounter of the problem, was before I had ICS, and I can't remember the option back then. I guess you could turn on the "Show touches" and film it, so you can do a slow motion replay and time the delay :P (Tap hard, so you can use the sound as a timing of the actual hit).  I'm not actively pursuing this problem anymore though.

Comment: I guess I was thinking more in the context of dragging around, where it's more noticeable. But yeah, it was a good idea to give up. Touch events are serialized between more than one process before you get them. Jelly Bean's Choreographer helped a little, but the devices I've tested on, there is at least a ~20ms lag that you can't avoid (even when using Window.takeInputQueue).

Comment: @Lionleaf, what kind of variance did you find in this delay on a single device?  I can imagine the delay becomes worse when the JVM is particularly busy, but supposing the device is in a static state (i.e. nothing else is running) did you see variance?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is Android or device issue. I have same problems with Galaxy Tab 10.1, Galaxy Note and Galaxy S II devices when develop NDK and GLES based apps, i.e. in contrast to iOS devices, lags between actual touch and receiving event on all "galaxies" depends to current gpu/cpu utilization, even if main (event processing) thread is do nothing, except processing theses events and all rendering and other things are performed in separated thread...

Comment: Yeah, I've gotten pretty sure myself that this is indeed the case. See my new answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the garbage collector doesn't run when you are handling the click event. If so, disable garbage collecting when your game is running. Otherwise, you are doing something expensive in your ui cycle that is causing stutter. Profiling your app should reveal the problem.

Comment: Stopping the garbage collector really isn't a solution, you will run out of memory and crash the app.

Comment: maybe he meant stop before the onTouch main body and start before the end of onTouch, but idk...

Comment: The garbage collector is a problem for the game, and I can notice every single one. But it's not what's causing this problem, and I know how to fix it. (Controlled GCs when there is time, and avoid dropping any garbage during the game by using pools etc)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but a direct answer to you question: no, there is no delay on android's side for a touch event.

Somewhere in your code is the source of the problem. It could be a variety of things.

For example, java is a multi-threaded language, so code does not necessarily run in a linear fashion. The Android UI thread will run on a different thread than your Surface, so they may not be syncing the way you expect.

Another possibility is that your controls are not getting touched. Are the touch areas small? iPhone has an excellent and responsive touch screen, but not all android devices are built to the same quality.

I wish I knew the specific cause, but i can let you safely eliminate the "its just freakin android" possibility. There is no delay caused by the OS.

Comment: Fantastic! :) As long as it's my fault, I'm sure I can work it out! The game runs in another thread than the UI (of course), so it might be a synchronization issue? I've tried adding synchronized blocks around the access to the critical variable (taps), but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. I guess I'll log timestamp throughout the path (even though that would cause some extra delay) and see if I can find the problem. Note though that I'm not talking about a big delay. Only, say 30 ms ish.

Comment: This response is patently incorrect.  There's always going to be a variable-length delay between the touch itself and routing that touch to the machine-language level handlers, through C code, and up through the JVM to produce a touch event.  In particular, the JVM is very unreliable at a level of 10's of milliseconds.